# How to pass data from one page to another page using phonegap for ios

Tags: ios, cordova, navigationbar

I am new to Phonegap programming.I created one HTML page(ListScreen.html) with NavigationBar plugin.In ListScreen I displayed list of data.When I select the one list item it goes to another HTML page that is DetailsScreen.html page.I tried the code in ListScreen.html as follows:

$(document).on("click", "#lstMyList li" ,function (event) {

```
    window.location.href='DetailsScreen.html';


    });
```

How to send the selected item from ListScreen.html to DetailsScreen.html.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly for me. try this way -

```
var foo = localStorage["bar"];
localStorage["bar"] = foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage. I supports any JavaScript object.

```
localStorage.setItem("oneKey", anObject);
var anObject = localStorage.getItem("oneKey");
```

Comment: ,Thanks but when I displayed the alert(anObject) ,it displays the selected item but when I am trying display in console as console.log(anObject) it does not display anything in console.

Comment: Would you put the object there?

Comment: I placed the localStorage.setItem("oneKey", anObject); in ListScreen.html and var anObject = localStorage.getItem("oneKey");console.log(anObject) in DetailsScreen.html then it does not displayed console text.

Comment: What's anObject in the console.log(anObject) in ListScreen.html just before localStorage.setItem("oneKey", anObject); And check localStorage.getItem("oneKey"); after localStorage.setItem("oneKey", anObject); in ListScreen.html

Comment: $(this).text(),this is the object means selected list item data

Comment: Did you check localStorage.getItem("oneKey"); after localStorage.setItem("oneKey", anObject); call?

Comment: If I wrote this line-localStorage.getItem("oneKey"); after localStorage.setItem("oneKey", anObject); in the same .html page it works perfect.but when I call another html page it does not

Comment: Well, That's hard though, I don't know why then.